# Colocar efeito suave ou lentidão em ancora (window.location.href)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

tenho o seguinte código:

```
if($('#otherfilter').is(':visible')){
  window.location.href='#otherfilter';
}
```

Gostaria de por uma certa lentidão para ele realizar essa ancora.

Comment: ja tinha visto, mas nao consegui implementar em meu codigo não :/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
                $('a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);

                  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top}, 1000,'easeInOutExpo');

            // Outras Animações
            // linear, swing, jswing, easeInQuad, easeInCubic, easeInQuart, easeInQuint, easeInSine, easeInExpo, easeInCirc, easeInElastic, easeInBack, easeInBounce, easeOutQuad, easeOutCubic, easeOutQuart, easeOutQuint, easeOutSine, easeOutExpo, easeOutCirc, easeOutElastic, easeOutBack, easeOutBounce, easeInOutQuad, easeInOutCubic, easeInOutQuart, easeInOutQuint, easeInOutSine, easeInOutExpo, easeInOutCirc, easeInOutElastic, easeInOutBack, easeInOutBounce


                });
            });
```

Para o html você pode seguir esta estrutura, link com a hashtag e o id na sessão onde quer que a página deslize